# bat file does not start and bat file is in a folder

Tags: java

I am trying to launch a bat file. The bat file is in a folder. The folder contains all the executable jar file. I tried this code to launch the bat file but unable.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NetBeansProjects\\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\\biodwh.startBioDWH.bat" );
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
      Process p = pb.start();
      InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
      for ( String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine() )
      {
              System.out.println( ">" + line ); 
      }
      p.waitFor();
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "unable". What does happen? What do you expect to happen? Is there an error message?

Comment: From my experience I'd like to point out that if a .bat file does not open, it may have nothing to do with the script you are making that is calling the .bat file. Several different types of errors could make the .bat file not work properly, or it could just be missing a pause that could make it look as if it's not functioning properly. In order to properly assess your code we would need to see what is inside of the .bat file. Since it seems none of the other answers are working for you, the .bat file having an error is my first instinct.

Answer (score 0):

try use this 
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\Users\user\Desktop\NetBeansProjects\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\biodwh.startBioDWH.bat");

Comment: i did add this line but it is not opening the bat file

Comment: it works for me..
try to remove first dot in your bat file name.

Comment: sorry but its not working for me because the bat file is in a folder which depends on the executable files that are there.

Comment: @VladimirScofild I think you forgot to double the backslaches and maybe it would work better by adding the `/d folderpath` parameter to the `start` command to force the folder

Answer (score 0):

in your .bat add the line `pushd %~dp0`

this will change the current drive and path to the one of the bat file.

Comment: no this is not opening the bat file. you are telling me to add pushd %~dp0 at the end of the path like that ( ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NetBeansProjects\\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\\biodwh.startBioDWH.batpushd %~dp0" )

Comment: no i tell you to modify the bat (if you can) file to add the line. Any .bat file should use `%~dp0` to handle path, this allows the batch file to always work would it be launched from inside it's path, by double click...

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to modify the bat file.Because once i doube click the bat file that is startBioDWH.bat starts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems I misunderstood the question.

I think you can't execute batch files directly but need to launch it using cmd.exe. Try adding `cmd /c` (with a space at the end) to your new ProcessBuilder line :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd /c C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NetBeansProjects\\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\\biodwh.startBioDWH.bat" );
```

Or ou can try to execute the bat file this way :

```
String path="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NetBeansProjects\\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\\";
File dir = new File(path);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+path+"biodwh.startBioDWH.bat", null, dir);
```

Or you can make it shorter if you don't need the batch file to be executed from the folder where it resides

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NetBeansProjects\\Genomic DataWarehouse Project\\biodwh.startBioDWH.bat");
```